# Why does $ \int _1^{\infty }\:\frac{\cos^2\left(x\right)}{x^2}dx $ converge?

Tags: calculus, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals

$$
\int _1^{\infty }\:\frac{\cos^2\left(x\right)}{x^2}dx
$$

How would one determine if this converges or diverges without integrating?

I attempted to integrate but ran into $\int \frac{\sin \left(u\right)}{u}du$ which I know is non elementary, but in my case, I can go no further with non elementary functions. (University Requirements).

My thought process went to breaking up the function and potentially comparing it to functions I already know converge. In this case, I know that $\int _1^{\infty }\frac{1}{x^2}dx$ converges to 1, but I don't know how to use that fact to show that the original function converges.

Comment: It is $\cos^2 x \leq 1$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that $\cos(x) \in [-1,1] \implies \cos^2(x) \in [0,1]$.

Hence,

$$0 \le \cos^2(x) \le 1 \implies 0 \le \int_1^\infty \frac{\cos^2(x)}{x^2} dx \le \int_1^\infty \frac{1}{x^2} dx$$

The direct comparison test ensures the convergence of the integral on this basis:

$$0 \le f(x) \le g(x) \implies 0 \le \int_a^b f(x)dx \le \int_a^b g(x) dx$$

and if the $g$ integral converges, so must $f$'s.

Answer (score 4):

Use comparison test for Integrals. $\cos^2 x$ is bounded.